# Coarsely equivalent spaces have the same asymptotic dimension

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces, metric-geometry

I am using the following definitions:

Let $X,Y$ be metric spaces.

We say that a map $f:X\to Y$ is **coarse** if:
$1.$ the pre-image of any bounded set in $Y$ under $f$ is bounded in $X$; and
$2.$ for any $R>0$ there exists $S>0$ such that for all $x,y\in X$ if $d_X(x,y)<R$ then $d_Y(f(x),f(y))<S$.

We say that a coarse map $f:X\to Y$ is a **coarse equivalence** if there exists a coarse map $g:Y\to X$ such that $d_Y(f\circ g(y),y)$ and $d_X(g\circ f(x),x)$ are (uniformly) bounded. That is, $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are close to the identity maps.

$X$ and $Y$ are coarsely equivalent if such a coarse equivalence exists.

Now, I want to show that if $X$ and $Y$ are coarsely equivalent then $asdim(x)=asdim(Y)$.

My approach:

Let $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to X$ be as above. Let $R>0$ be given.
Let $S>0$ be such that if $d_X(x,y)<R$ then $d_Y(f(x),f(y))<S$.
Let $\mathcal{U}=\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a uniformly bounded cover for $Y$ with $S$-multiplicity $asdimY+1$.
Let $\mathcal{V}=\{f^{-1}(U_i)\}_{i\in I}$ be a uniformly bounded (since $f$ pulls back bounded sets to bounded sets) cover of $X$.
By construction $B_R(x)$ intersects as many elements of $\mathcal{V}$ as the number of elements of $\mathcal{U}$ intersecting $f(B_R(x))$. But $f(B_R(x))\subseteq B_S(f(x))$.
Since $B_S(f(x))$ intersecting at most $asdimY+1$ elements of $\mathcal{U}$, we obtain $asdimX\leq asdimY$.
Now, use coarsity of $g$ to show $asdimY\leq asdimX$.

The problem is that I actually didn't use the fact that the compositions are close to the identity maps. So, I've shown that whenever $f:X\to Y$ is a coarse map, $asdimX\leq asdimY$, which I suspect to be true.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: The problem, as I see it, is that you misstated the definition of a coarse map: You want uniform control on diameters of preimages of bounded sets: $diam(B)\le r\Rightarrow diam(f^{-1}(B))\le R(r)$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I quoted the definition appears in the books: John Roe- "Lectures on coarse geometry" and "Large scale geometry" by Piotr W. Nowak and Guoliang Yu.

Comment: But what you are using in the proof is the definition that I gave. You can use the other definition, but then you need to verify that you have uniform bounds on preimages and this is where you would need to know that $f\circ g$ is within finite distance from the identity map.

Comment: @MoisheCohen Sorry, I thought I understood and again I have doubts.
Probably, you mean that the problematic part is the claim that $\mathcal{V}=\{f^-1(U_i)\}_{i\in I}$ is a uniformly bounded cover. However, since $\mathcal{U}$ was a uniformly bounded cover of $Y$, we can choose large enough ball, $B$, that contains all the elements in $\mathcal{U}$. Since $f$ is proper $f^{-1}(B)$ is bounded, i.e. contained in some ball of finite radius. But then each element of $\mathcal{V}$ is in that ball, so $\mathcal{V}$ is uniformly bounded. Is it the problem you mentioned?

Comment: No, you cannot find a bonded subset containing all elements of your uniformly bounded cover.

Comment: Yes, of course, right, Thank you.